# Does push_back() always increase a vector's size?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, push-back

I have a piece of code which creates a std::vector<T> with a known size:

```
std::vector<T> vectorOfTs(n);
```

Does calling push_back increase the size to n+1?

```
vectorOfTs.push_back(T());
```

Comment: You included memory allocation as a tag; could you elaborate on what you expect and what's confusing you in that aspect?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes; note that `vector<T>.capacity()` is different from `vector<T>.size()`. The latter denotes the number of elements currently in the vector while the former represents the number of items that fit in the space currently allocated for the vector's internal buffer.

Answer (score 10):

Almost.  If there are no exceptions, then `size()` will increment.

`push_back(T())` could also throw an exception at various stages: see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), or summarily:

- `T()` construction, in which case no call to `push_back` takes place, and `size()` is unaffected
- if the `vector` needs to increase the capacity, that may throw, in which case `size()` is unaffected
- the `vector` element will be copy or move constructed using `std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);`, if `A` is `std::allocator<T>`, then this will call placement-`new`, as by `::new((void*)p) T(v)`: if any of this throws the `vector`'s `size()` is unaffected, ****unless***

  - the move constructor isn't `noexcept` and does throw: in which case the effects are unspecified
- the vector update's then complete - `size()` will have incremented and the value will be in the `vector` (even if `T::~T()`)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you instead want to reserve space, call reserve(), e.g.:

```
std::vector<T> vectorOfTs;
vectorOfTs.reserve(n);
// now size() == 0, capacity() >= n

vectorOfTs.push_back(T());
// now size() == 1
```

Comment: Your answer seems a bit ambiguous, at best. `reserve` will *not* change the size, it just reserves memory (and therefore may change `capacity`).

Comment: Hmm really? I was presenting this as a different option, if the OP's intention is to pre-allocate memory for a vector of size n rather than have a vector of n default constructed Ts, he could use `reserve()`, but the main answer is "Yes".

Comment: You were 99% of the way there; I tried to edit and remove the ambiguity GMan mentioned.  (The original question is vague on what is expected and what's confusing about the allocation aspect.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
std::vector<T> vectorOfTs(n);
```

In the above statement, actually you are constructing 'n' number of new instances of type T (i.e. default constructor T() would be triggered for each time). Now vector vectorOfTs contains n elements.  The following version of the vector constructor would be invoked for the above statement.

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

So, when you push back another element into vector, size of vector would be n+1.